# How to remove years with different numbers that are in the middle of sentences

Tags: excel, function, vba

In Excel, for the following data, I want years with different numbers to be removed:

Honda Motorcycle 1983 XR350R A CAMSHAFT + VALVE

Honda ATV 1999 TRX400EX A - FOURTRAX 400EX CAMSHAFT + VALVE

Moreover, I want the data to be looking like the following:

Honda Motorcycle XR350R A CAMSHAFT + VALVE

Honda ATV TRX400EX A - FOURTRAX 400EX CAMSHAFT + VALVE

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a RegEx - have you tried at all?  If so, please post your code so that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, this will remove years between 1900 and 2020:

```
Sub YearKiller()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
    For Each r In rng
        msg = ""
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, " ") <> 0 Then
            ary = Split(v, " ")
            For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
                a = ary(i)
                If Len(a) = 4 And IsNumeric(a) Then
                    n = CDbl(a)
                    If n > 1900 And n < 2020 Then
                        ary(i) = " "
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            r.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(ary, " "))
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```